# Merge corresponding elements from multiple arrays

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have below inputs

**input 1**:

```
[{
    "id": "3857"
}, {
    "id": "57"
}]
```

**input 2**:

```
[{
    "Date": "2022-11-30",
    "name": "salesorder",
    "brand": "Apple",
    "Requests": "111",
    "price": "917.65"
}, {
    "Date": "2022-11-13",
    "name": "orders",
    "brand": "TV",
    "Requests": "11",
    "price": "91.60"
}]
```

**input 3**:

```
[{
    "count": "3"
}, {
    "count": "4"
}]
```

**input 4**:

```
[{
    "stock": "21",
    "sold": "112"
}, {
    "stock": "2",
    "sold": "12"
}]
```

**Desired Output**:

```
[{
        "id": "3857",
        "Date": "2022-11-30",
        "name": "salesorder",
        "brand": "Apple",
        "Requests": "111",
        "price": "917.65",
        "count": "3",
        "stock": "21",
        "sold": "112"
    },
    {
        "id": "57",
        "Date": "2022-11-13",
        "name": "orders",
        "brand": "TV",
        "Requests": "11",
        "price": "91.60",
        "count": "4",
        "stock": "2",
        "sold": "12"
    }
]
```

Comment: You should separate and format the values for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all arrays have the same size you can map each element of the concatenation of the key-values from each item using the index number of each element being mapped (`$$` by default).

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var input1=[{"id": "3857"},{"id": "57"}]
var input2=[{"Date": "2022-11-30","name": "salesorder","brand": "Apple","Requests": "111","price":"917.65"},{"Date": "2022-11-13","name": "orders","brand": "TV","Requests": "11","price": "91.60"}] 
var input3=[{"count": "3" },{"count": "4" }]
var input4=[{"stock": "21","sold": "112"},{"stock": "2","sold": "12"}]
---
input1 map (input1[$$] ++ input2[$$] ++ input3[$$] ++ input4[$$])
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "3857",
    "Date": "2022-11-30",
    "name": "salesorder",
    "brand": "Apple",
    "Requests": "111",
    "price": "917.65",
    "count": "3",
    "stock": "21",
    "sold": "112"
  },
  {
    "id": "57",
    "Date": "2022-11-13",
    "name": "orders",
    "brand": "TV",
    "Requests": "11",
    "price": "91.60",
    "count": "4",
    "stock": "2",
    "sold": "12"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [zip](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-zip) function to combine the arrays together, and then the `++` operator to merge the objects together:

```
fun combineTwo(input1, input2) = (input1 zip input2) // produces an array of two element arrays
    map ($[0] ++ $[1]) // combines the two elements into a single object
```

Then you can use [reduce](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-reduce) to do this with an arbitrary number of input arrays like so:

```
[input1, input2, input3, input4] reduce (item, result) -> combineTwo(result, item)
```

Comment: Using the zip() function is a great idea, however the answer should clarify how to extend the method for more than two arrays.

Comment: good point, I'll extend it to use reduce